# Pattern for dependency between gui components

Tags: java, design-patterns, model-view-controller, user-interface

In a Swing Gui, every component refers, by design, to its own data model to display data. Although they don't refer to a common model, sometimes components can 
be "dependent" to each other, because of the semantic of the program.

For example: if the Gui has a JToggleButton that shows/hides a table and another JButton, 
whose actionListener counts the rows in that table, the latter must be disabled when the former is not selected (and the table not visible). Indeed - let's suppose- counting the rows of a non visible table might lead to an inconsistent state. Say, for example, that
when the table is hidden the JButton's actionListener calls a method on a variable that is set to null.

I know this is a very trivial example. But it has happened to me, quite often, that I had to kind of look at all these dependencies between components. And I had to disable some components, so as to prevent the user from bringing the program to an inconsistent state, by clicking on the wrong button at the wrong time.

Therefore, I have started wondering if there is a more organized and standard way to address this problem, than just skimming trough the code and place some setEnable(false), here and there, where I notice there is a dependency.

A way to go, I think, could be to have a dependency matrix of boolean values: one row for each possible state of the interface, and one column for each component of the interface. *matrix[i][j]* would be *true* if at state *i*, the component *j* must be disabled. and *false* otherwise.

What to you think about it ? Is there any kind of design pattern to address this problem ?

cheers

Comment: I tend to use an event bus for these types of problems. They allow for loosely coupled code - the parties involved do not have to know about each other, but just the events themselves. I have used the one offered by Google Guava and also MBassador to great effect. I would say massive matrix of `boolean` is best avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully sure what you mean by your "state i", how general or concrete this is. In some situations you may use a simple helper object like this below and have an instance of it for each observed state. The component whose state you are dependent on will have no compile-time dependency on the related components, but will have a reference to its instance of DependentComponents.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Handles components which are enabled/disabled based on some condition
 */
public class DependentComponents {
    /**
     * Internal set of components handled by this object
     */
    final private Set<Component> components = new HashSet<>();

    /**
     * Each dependent component should be added to the set by this method
     * 
     * @param component A component which is to be added
     */
    public void register(final Component component) {
        this.components.add(component);
    }

    /**
     * Enables or disables all the components, depending on the value of the parameter b. 
     * 
     * @param b If <code>true</code>, all the components are enabled; otherwise they are disabled
     */
    public void setEnabled(boolean b) {
        for (Component component : this.components) {
            component.setEnabled(b);
        }
    }
}
```